# How can I maintain equal flex height for multiple lists / list items?

Tags: html, css, list, flexbox, height

I have 2 dynamic lists which sit as siblings one on top of the other using a flex column layout. My dilemma is that I cannot seem to get the lists/list items to maintain an equal flex height, as the list with fewer items always seems to stretch the height of its items.

Please see my code below. Notice how "item 1, list 2" has stretched? I want all the list items for both lists to conform and have equal height to fill out the main parent container. A `ul` with a single `li` item should resize to the height of a single `li` item.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.list-item {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">item 1, list 1</li>
    <li class="list-item">item 2, list 1</li>
    <li class="list-item">item 3, list 1</li>
    <li class="list-item">item 4, list 1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">item 1, list 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you wanting to have the `li` elements to have the same height no matter which `ul` they appear in?

Comment: You see how list 2, item one has stretched to fill almost half the container? I want it to be 1/5 of the size, along with the rest of the list items. of course their height can change the more items added, but they should all be equal height. In short - yes.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. What should happen to the parent `ul`?  Should it _shrink_ to the size of the single `li` or should it remain at the default height?

Comment: It should shrink to the size of a single `li`

Comment: Do you have any ideas @Martin ? I'm kinda lost haha

Comment: I've been toying with this trying to get it to behave but it doesn't want to.  The problem is getting the `li` in the second list to behave like the first.  Have you considered setting a `max-height` on the `li` elements?

Comment: If i give the `li` elements a max height then there's a huge gap left at the bottom of the `ul` which is still flexing to match parent height

Comment: Just remove the flex 1 from the lists

Comment: Removing flex 1 from the lists prevents them from filling the parent space

Comment: Hello. I post an answer to your problem. I hope It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have solved your problem. First of all, because you gave that **container** class element ** height: 500px;** it affect your ul, li elements height. I removed them from your CSS and in **list-item** class I added **min-height:100px;** but you can change the height of the ***li*** elements according to what you want.

> 

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width:100%;
  flex:0 0 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.list-item {
  min-height:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">item 1, list 1</li>
    <li class="list-item">item 2, list 1</li>
    <li class="list-item">item 3, list 1</li>
    <li class="list-item">item 4, list 1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">item 1, list 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```